# cakephp 3 form input with type 'timestamp' in db [Internal Error]

Tags: php, cakephp, timestamp, cakephp-3.x

It direct me to error page 'inter error' after i click the submit button. Anything else I need to add?
Thank you if anyone can help, please..
btw, i am using cakephp 3.xx

```
echo $this->Form->input('inputDate', array('type'=>'text'));        

$validator
->add('inputDate', 'valid', ['rule' => 'timestamp'])
->requirePresence('inputDate', 'create')
->notEmpty('inputDate');
```

**'inputDate' in DB: Type is 'timestamp', default set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp3 haven't the **timestamp** rule. you can create custom validation rule in cakephp. **[custom validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules)**

first of all you should turn on the debug tool for details viewing of the error:

1. open PROJECT\config\app.php file.
2. 'debug' => **false** to 'debug' => **true**

Comment: alright. Got it. Thank for your time ya.

btw, let say the current time i am showing now is 05:00pm, is there any attributes allow me to +5 hour for the hour field?
Like for example  we can do date('Y')+1 for the max or min year, so how about the hour.. i am doing this because the utc issue.
Thanks.
    echo $this->Form->input('receiptDate', array(
        'label' => 'Receipt Date', 
        'maxYear'=>date('Y')+1, 
        'timeFormat'=>'12',
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
    ));

Comment: you can use it - **date('H:i', time() + 60*300)**  to increase the time and accept the answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: hey really appreciate your help, thank you. Will mark yours as answer.